# High CPU utilization KSQL db

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-eks, ksqldb

We are running KSQL db server on kubernetes cluster.
**Node config:**

> AWS EKS fargate
> No of nodes: 1
> CPU: 2 vCPU (Request), 4 vCPU (Limit)
> RAM: 4 GB (Request), 8 GB (Limit)
> Java heap: 3 GB (Default)

**Data size:**
We have ~11 source topic with 1 partition, some one them having 10k record few has more than 100k records. ~7 sink topic but to create those 7 sink topic have ~60 ksql table, ~38 ksql streams & ~64 persistent queries because of joins and aggregation. So heavy computation.

**KSQLdb version:** `0.23.1` and we are using confluent official KSQL docker image

---

**The problem:**
When running our KSQL script we are seeing spike in CPU to 350-360% and memory 20-30%. And when that happen kubernetes restarting the server instance. Which is resulting ksql-migration to fail.

Error:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection 
refused: 
<deployment-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local/172.20.73.150:8088
Error: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Connection was closed
```

We have 30 migration files, and each file has multiple table and stream creation.
And its always failing on v27.

**What we have tried so far:**

- Running it alone. And in that case it pass with no error.
- Increase initial CPU to 4 vCPU but no change in CPU utilization
- Had 2 nodes with 2 partition in kafka, but that also had same issue with addition few data columns having no data.

---

So something is not right in our configuration or resource allocation.
What's the standard of deployment for KSQL in kubernetes? maybe its not meant for kubernetes.

Comment: [Update] We tried with 4 CPU (or 8 vCPU), and that fixes the problem as of now. What we understand so far when we have 500k data in kafka topic, at time when it processes the CPU us going high as much as 500%

Comment: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/capacity-planning/ This might be helpful.

Comment: as normal basic suggested is :-->
4 cores
32 GB RAM
100 GB SSD
1 Gbit network